# How to stop Timer after few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer, dispatch-queue

Here in `myAPICall()` method am calling another method I.e., `COStatusAPI()` for every 5 seconds upto 90 seconds.

Here `COStatusAPI()` is an API call. i.e., Am hitting server for every 5 seconds.  In response I’ll get **COStatus as 1 or 0**.

If I get **COStatus as 1**, am stopping the timer and navigating to another viewController
and
If I get COStatus as 0 for 90 seconds. I am stopping the timer and showing alert.

But here my issue is timer is not getting stop. like, If I get **COStatus as 1**, in background timer is running. So, after 90 seconds am getting alert message.

In the same way until 90 seconds. If I am getting **COStatus as 0** means am showing alert. This alert is go on repeating.

how to achieve this?. Could anyone help me with this

```
var myTimer : Timer?
var timeController : Bool = true

func myAPICall(){
    self.loadingview()
        if self.myTimer == nil {
             self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.COStatusAPI), userInfo: nil, repeats: self.timeController)
             }
}

@objc func COStatusAPI(){
        if COStatus == 0{
            self.timeController = true
            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 90
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
                self.timeController = false
                if self.acceptOrRejectTimer != nil {
                    self.acceptOrRejectTimer!.invalidate()
                    self.acceptOrRejectTimer = nil
                }
                self.hideloadingView()
        //showing alert
            }
        }
        if COStatus == 1{
                self.timeController = false
                if self.acceptOrRejectTimer != nil {
                    self.acceptOrRejectTimer!.invalidate()
                    self.acceptOrRejectTimer = nil
                }
                self.hideloadingview()
        //navigating to next view controller
        }
```

}

Comment: If you use pods then the [AsyncTimer](https://github.com/Decybel07/AsyncTimer) can be helpful for you

Comment: thank you @AdrianBobrowski. vadian's code worked like charm. now no need to use  dispatchqueue, async timer and all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Forget `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`.
- Create an `Int` counter property with value 18.
- In `COStatusAPI()` make the API call.
- if `COStatus == 1`

  - `invalidate()` the timer and go to the next controller.
- else

  - decrement the counter.
  - if the counter reaches 0 `invalidate()` the timer and show the alert.

---

```
var myTimer : Timer?
var counter = 0

func myAPICall(){
    self.loadingview()
    if self.myTimer == nil {
        counter = 18
        self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0,
                                            target: self,
                                            selector: #selector(COStatusAPI),
                                            userInfo: nil,
                                            repeats: true)
    }
}

@objc func COStatusAPI(_ timer: Timer) {

    // call API
    switch COStatus {
    case 0: 
        counter -= 1
        if counter == 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.myTimer = nil
            //showing alert
        }
    case 1: 
        timer.invalidate()
        self.myTimer = nil
        //navigating to next view controller

    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the quick response. if you don't mine, could you provide code. still am not able to get output

Comment: what is counter = 18 here? does 18 means 18 seconds ?

Comment: i have to stop my timer after 90 seconds & we have to show alert? were do we need to mention here that timer should run for 90 seconds?

Comment: The timer fires every 5 seconds and 18 * 5 = 90